# Is there a C# code in unity to identify when a Button is pressed and when it is released?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to set up a code in C# that identifies when a certain button is pressed and when it is released

I'm trying to make this certain button scale down when pressed and scale up when released

```
public class clickshake : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject click;
    public void Update()
    {    
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
           transform.localScale += new Vector3(-0.1F, -0.1f, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
           transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1F, 0.1f, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

by making this script exclusive to the button in its On Click command
it only grew the button in size and didn't shrink it down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> making this script exclusive to the button in its On Click  command

that makes little sense. Especially since the `Update` method is called all the time every frame. So calling it additionally from the `onClick` will call it twice in that frame. Also from `Button.onClick`

> Note that `EventType.MouseDown` and `EventType.MouseUp` are called prior to [`onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html).

---

You can e.g. use the [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) and [`IPointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) interfaces to implement that

```
public class clickshake : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    //Detect current clicks on the GameObject (the one with the script attached)
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.1F, 0.1f, 0);
    }

    //Detect if clicks are no longer registering
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1F, 0.1f, 0);
    }
}
```

Note

> Ensure an `EventSystem` exists in the Scene to allow click detection. For click detection on **non-UI** GameObjects, ensure a `PhysicsRaycaster` is attached to the Camera.

and non-UI objects ofcourse will also need a `Collider`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code worked perfectly, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is triggered when the button is **pressed**, since you call it when the button is already pressed, it doesn't trigger.

> **Input.GetMouseButtonDown**
>
> Returns true during the frame the user pressed the given mouse button.

*https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html*

try tu use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` instead.

Or call it elsewhere than in the `OnClick()`.

But be aware that `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` if in a loop, will trigger multiple time since its detects when the button is held down.

**EDIT**
By trigger I mean that its returns `True` so it triggers your `if`